# "ValueError: Improper config format" TensorFlow Keras unable to load config from JSON file

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have been using this script to load a model in .h5 format and save it as SavedModel:

```
import json
import tensorflow.keras as keras

with open('/path/to/file.json', 'r') as f:
    model_json = json.load(f)

model_str = json.dumps(model_json) 

model = keras.models.model_from_json(model_str)
model.load_weights('/path/to/weights.h5')

# Export the model to a SavedModel
keras.models.save_model(model, 
    '/path/to/destination'
)
```

However, when running `model_from_json()` I get the following:

```
ValueError: Improper config format: {'h5': '/path/to/weights.h5', 'labels': ['label1',..., 'labeln']}
```

I'd like to point out there is only two variables in the JSON file: 'h5' which is the path to my weights file and 'labels' which contains a list of available labels for prediction.

I save the JSON file like this:

```
cfg = {
        'h5': os.path.join(PATH, 'weights.h5'),
        'labels': original_labels.tolist()
    }

with open(os.path.join(PATH, 'file.json'), 'w+') as file:
        json.dump(cfg, file)
```

Comment: Where did you get this json from? It does not look like a valid keras model JSON file

Comment: I manually made it (there's an update in the post). I have tried looking for valid formats but I haven't found anything clear.

Comment: I think you have the completely wrong approach, we do not make JSON files to load keras models, they are produced by Keras, so I am not sure exactly what are you trying to do? Do you have a H5 file with the model already?

Comment: Yes, I have a .h5 weights file I have used for prediction. Is that all I need for exporting as a SavedModel format?

Comment: The H5 file can be loaded using keras.models.load_model, your .h5 file should contain both model and weights.

Comment: The .h5 file only contains the model weights. While loading them using `keras.Model.load_weights('weights.h5')` I get another error, but I think I should make another thread for that.